# Cómo puedo llamar un procedimiento almacenado de sql server en una function jquery asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en `sql server` que me devuelve un numero de turno a partir de dos nombres, eso funciona correctamente.

El problema es que quiero adaptar ese SP en una funcion jquery para no tener que agregar un botón y obtener ese numero, ya que me recargaría toda la pagina, en cambio con jquery puedo obtenerlo automático con los 2 dropdownlists de los nombres.

Al momento solo he capturado los nombres, el paso siguiente debería ser llamar al método del SP

```
<script>
var conductor = $('#footer_ddconductor option:selected').text(); 
var auxiliar = $('footer_ddauxiliar option:selected').text(); 
</script>
```

Comment: Mi amigo pero porque no lo agregas en el load el Sp llamando desde asp.net ?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el evento change y una llamada ajax para que cada que cambie la opcion seleccionada se ejecute el evento y se haga una llamada al servidor para consultar el metodo C# que ejecuta el procedimiento almacenado

te dejo un ejemplo:

**codigo javascript:**

```
$("#NombreDrop").on("change", function () {

$.ajax({
    url: "ArchivoASP.aspx/LLamaProcedimiento",
    data: {},
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
     var respuesta = data;
    },
    error: function (result) {
        MensajeError("ERROR " + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
    }
});
})
```

**Codigo C#:**

```
[WebMethod]

public static string LLamaProcedimiento()
{
   //Codigo que ejecuta el procedimiento almacenado

    return respuestaProcedimiento;
}
```